# How to prevent loading the same data over and over in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that contains some data that I need to load when my application starts. Once its loaded I need to be able to reuse in multiple places on my application.

What is the best way to do this?

Right now I have a factory that I inject into my controller and I pull the data, the problem is that I'm doing the data pull multiple times.

What would be the best way to pull the data only when I load the application?
I would only need to access the data on my templates and pull the correct Key Value from the object where I need.

Comment: Create a model and service for said loaded data, that way you will have a layer of abstraction to control it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an angularjs service instead of a factory.  Services in angularjs are singleton where factories are not.

You should be able to just change how your factory is registered to make it a service instead.

```
var yourModule = angular.module('yourModule', []);
yourModule.service(
```

instead of

```
yourModule.factory(
```

more info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that should solve my issue. So service will only generate one instance thru out my application and factory does not do that? I'm new to angularJS :)

Comment: Correct, when a factory is injected a new instance is created each time.  When a service is injected the same instance is injected each time.  Let me know if you still have issues but a service should do the trick.